# MS Access Application - Render a Command Button inactive until specific criteria is met in a Form

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, conditional-statements

I built an application in MS Access 2010 where end-users are posting statements.  On **Form 1** the end-user enters the **Statement Total** and other info, then clicks on the Command Button which appends a table to begin tracking the end-users entries and takes them to **Form 2**.

**Form 2** is populated with the data entered on **Form 1** as well as other data from joined tables.  Here, the user breaks out the statement total by **invoice amounts**.  A field named **Balance Check** calculates the difference between the **invoice amounts** and the **Statement Total** from **Form 1**.  Once the **Balance Check** equals **$0** they then click on the **command button** named **Finish Statement**.

I need a **snipit of code** that will **render the Finish Statement command button inactive** until the **Balance Check = $0**.  Also, even once the **Balance Check = $0** I still want a pop-up box to appear when they click on **Finish Statment** that asks **Are you sure you are finished? Yes or No** that will allow them to cancel the operation.

Here is the code I am currently using for this command button:

---

```
Private Sub Command160_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Command160_Click

    Dim stDocName As String

    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.Echo False

    stDocName = "BNK01-FillInfo"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery stDocName, acNormal, acEdit
    DoCmd.OpenReport "BNK01Report"
    Dim PdfFileNameToStore As String
    PdfFileNameToStore = "N:\Corp Office\Midwest Center\AR Department\Statement Processing\Invoice Reports\Sup01\BNK01\" & Forms.BNK01Nav.cboStore & "-" & Forms.BNK01Nav.txtReference & "-" & Forms.BNK01Nav.txtStmtAmt & "-BNK01" & ".pdf"
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "BNK01Report", acFormatPDF, PdfFileNameToStore, False
    stDocName = "BNK01-AddCredit"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery stDocName, acNormal, acEdit
    stDocName = "BNK01-AddDebit"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery stDocName, acNormal, acEdit
    stDocName = "BNK01-AddChargebacks"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery stDocName, acNormal, acEdit
    stDocName = "BNK01ClearChargebacks"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery stDocName, acNormal, acEdit
    stDocName = "BNK01-SaveEntry"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery stDocName, acNormal, acEdit
    stDocName = "BNK01-PostedNewStatement"
    DoCmd.OpenQuery stDocName, acNormal, acEdit
    stDocName = "BNK01EntryReport"
    DoCmd.OpenReport stDocName, acViewPreview
    stDocName = "BNK01Form"
    DoCmd.Close acForm, stDocName, acSaveYes


    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    DoCmd.Echo True

Exit_command160_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_Command160_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_command160_Click

End Sub
```

---

Sorry if the explanation is long, but I am very new to this and want to make sure I give adequate info.  Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: Look into setting the Enabled property of the button to false when opening the form (form Open event), and setting Enabled to true when all the conditions are met.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Balance_Check_AfterUpdate()
    If Me.Balance_Check.Value = "0" Then
        Me.Finish_Statement.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Finish_Statement_Click()
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you are finished?", vbDefaultButton1 + vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Finished?") = vbYes Then
        'processing code goes here
    End If
End Sub
```

I wasn't real sure of your object names, but I think you'll figure it out.
Good luck.

Comment: Sooo close! The enabled/disable isn't working, but I will keep playing with it.  The pop-up box is appearing but regardless of the option you choose, yes or no, the macro continues runnning and then crashes.  I hate being so new to this.

Comment: I wasn't sure where Balance Check was calculated. I had to guess at a control named Balance Check. Also, this code goes in your form code, not a module.